# UITableviewCell subview appears only on scrolling or cell reuse (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

As in the image below, the `UITableView` subview appears only on tableview reload or cell reuse (during scrolling, mostly). The blue color circle is what I want in my `UITableViewCell`. When it first appears, it will be a small dot as you can see in the picture, and on scrolling or refreshing the tableview, it appears as the full circle.

What can be the issue?

[image: Screen image]

I use the following code in `cellforRowAtIndexPath` method

```
cell.categoryRoundBackground.layer.cornerRadius=cell.categoryRoundBackground.frame.size.height/2;
```

Comment: set masktobound to YES also

Comment: DO you know why it is happening?

Comment: just debug by setting any static corner radius value.Then you will come to know.Most probably it will be a frame issue

Comment: @abhi1992 You asked "why is this happening?" not just "how do I fix this?" The answer to either question (such as those answers below) depend upon **how** you are creating your table view cells. Are you using a Storyboard, a Nib file (CustomCell.xib) or programmatically? Are you registering your Custom Cell subclass, and if so how? (`registerNib:` or `registerClass:`). Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, are you using the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to create your table cells, or some other method?

Comment: I was using storyboard to create the cell.The issue was the one which dasblinkenlight said and 

Muhammad Waqas Bhati,s answer solved it.

Answer (score 2):

try using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomTableViewCell *cell1 = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that at the moment when you access your cell's frame height the first time by calling

```
cell.categoryRoundBackground.frame.size.height / 2
```

the cell has never been placed in a table view, it has no idea what its frame height is going to be, and so it uses some default value. The actual height depends on the value returned by your code in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

You can work around this problem by computing the frame size yourself. You should be able to do that, because your code supplies the value to `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you change the corner radius before that the view layouts its subviews.
You should try to put the line

```
cell.categoryRoundBackground.layer.cornerRadius=cell.categoryRoundBackground.frame.size.height/2;
```

inside

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to Override the method in **CustomTableViewCell**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.categoryRoundBackground.layer.cornerRadius=self.categoryRoundBackground.frame.size.height/2;
   self.categoryRoundBackground.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

and In **CellForRowAtIndexPath:** you have to write these lines at the end

```
// Update layout
[cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: These code should go inside CustomTableViewCell m file right?

Comment: it worked only for ios 7 device.THe issue is still there in ios 9 iphone.Is there any difference in calling of `layoutIfNeeded` in ios 9 ?I wonder why it won't work.The logic of the code is correct.